# Next.js render component based on selected item

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using Next.js to create a web app where a user, once logged in, have a sidebar with different options (contents), I have a page under `/dashboard/[id].js` that the user is pushed once logged in.

Next, I have an array representing different components and some options related to them:

```
const contents = [
  { name: "spreadsheet", component: <Spreadsheet /> },
  { name: "streamlit", component: <StreamlitEmbed /> },
];
```

those contents are being rendered in a sidebar, where I want the first element to be rendered by default:

```
{contents.map((content) => {
                  console.log(content);
                  return (
                    <SidebarElement
                      text={content.name}
                      router={router}
                      iconName={`/${content.name}.svg`}
                      isSelected={
                        contents.findIndex((c) => c === content) === 0
                      }
                    />
                  );
                })}
```

I want the dashboard to be able to render the component that the user selected from the sidebar, I am not sure if the build-in router in Next.js would be able to do something like that. Since I am looking for an approach more similar to r[eact-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route)

I have thought about appending to the URL the name of the content so that on load I will have a URL with the first content name, and when a user clicks on another content that URL is being changed and the user redirected, but it seems to them that doing this approach would require to have `n` pages, one for each content which, ideally, should be dynamically generated.

Just for reference, I append the whole `Dashboard.js`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";

import StreamlitEmbed from "../../components/StreamlitEmbed";
import Header from "../../components/Header";
import Spinner from "../../components/Spinner/Spinner";
import SidebarElement from "../../components/SidebarElement";
import Spreadsheet from "../../components/Spreadsheet/Spreadsheet";

const contents = [
  { name: "spreadsheet", component: <Spreadsheet /> },
  { name: "streamlit", component: <StreamlitEmbed /> },
];

import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

function Dashboard() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState(false);

  const displayName = user?.attributes["custom:displayName"];
  const groups =
    user?.signInUserSession.accessToken.payload["cognito:groups"] || [];

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
        .then((user) => {
          setUser(user);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          setUser(null);
          router.push("/login");
        });
    };
    getUser();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {user ? (
        <div>
          <div className="flex h-screen">
            <div
              onClick={() => setSidebarOpen(false)}
              className={`${
                sidebarOpen ? "block" : "hidden"
              } fixed z-20 inset-0 bg-primaryColor opacity-50 transition-opacity lg:hidden`}
            />
            <div
              className={`${
                sidebarOpen
                  ? "translate-x-0 ease-out"
                  : "-translate-x-full ease-in"
              } fixed z-30 inset-y-0 left-0 w-64 transition duration-300 transform bg-primaryColor overflow-y-auto lg:translate-x-0 lg:static lg:inset-0 bg-main`}
            >
              <div className="flex items-center justify-center mt-8">
                <div className="flex items-center">
                  <Image src={"/logo.svg"} height={85} width={100} />
                </div>
              </div>
              <nav className="mt-10">
                {contents.map((content) => {
                  console.log(content);
                  return (
                    <SidebarElement
                      text={content.name}
                      router={router}
                      iconName={`/${content.name}.svg`}
                      isSelected={
                        contents.findIndex((c) => c === content) === 0
                          ? true
                          : false
                      }
                    />
                  );
                })}
              </nav>
              <div className="p-2 absolute bottom-0 left-2 text-gray-200">
                <p>V 2.0</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col overflow-hidden">
              <Header
                setSidebarOpen={setSidebarOpen}
                displayName={displayName}
                groups={groups}
              />

              <Spreadsheet />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Spinner />
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```